# What is the largest and/or heaviest object that could be sent to space?

Tags: launch, mass

What is the largest and/or heaviest object that could be sent to space? I know the space station is sent in pieces but I am looking with one launch.

Comment: Related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/whats-the-largest-single-object-payload-ever-lifted-into-space?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The Moon? Of course, it required advanced techniques, and there were some side effects...

Comment: The claimed numbers for the SLS are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Launch_System#Payload_mass Anyone's guess when or if it will fly and what the payload will really be.

Comment: Are you asking about what could be done now, or have been done in recent history, or about fundamental scientific limits to what could be done in the future? Your question isn't quite clear.

Comment: If it should be large only, a balloon satellite like [Echo 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Echo) with a diameter of 41 m will be the largest possible object.

Comment: Also, "to space", is quite vague. Just reach the Kármán line (100 km ASL, the commonly accepted limit between the atmosphere and space)? Get into LEO? Get into another orbit? Reach escape velocity?

Comment: @jcaron - yes - especially since we're already in space.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Historically, the heaviest payloads that reached orbit were the Apollo missions; the third stage of the Saturn V booster plus the Apollo spacecraft combined exceeded 140 tons in low Earth orbit. The lower two stages alone could put over 120 tons in orbit; such a configuration was used to launch the Skylab space station in a single 77-ton piece.

Today, the highest-capacity operational launcher is the Falcon Heavy, allegedly capable of putting over 50 tons into orbit (though the figures are pretty unclear). Delta IV Heavy (28 tons) and Long March 5 (25 tons) are the 2nd and 3rd place finishers.

Unlike the largest historical launchers (Saturn V, Energia, and STS), which carried payload at least partially externally (if you count the STS orbiter as payload), the modern heavy lift launchers expect the payload to be entirely contained within a fairing, which sets limits on the physical size of the payload. Long March 5 and Falcon use a 5.2 meter diameter fairing, Delta IV a 5.1 meter fairing -- various different lengths are available.

Comment: Payload mass for Block 2 for the Space Launch System is expected to be able to place over 140 tons into Low Earth Orbit. Until SLS, BFR, Long March 9 fly, Saturn V is the only proven heavy lifter. -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_heavy-lift_launch_vehicle#Comparison

Answer (score 8):

I believe the plan is for SpaceX BFR to be able to take **150** tons into space:

[image]

Reference

- [SpaceX Mars Official Website](http://www.spacex.com/mars)

Comment: More content would help maybe some stats on each.+1

Answer (score 2):

There is no sensible limit to how much could be launched, just a mater of practicality.

Project Orion's aimed for it's interstellar craft to take [5500 tonnes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)#Sizes_of_Orion_vehicles) to LEO, as a "conventional" launcher, Sea Dragon aimed at 550 tonnes.

Comment: but orion project, using an atomic pulse engine never had a plan on how to use it before reaching orbit without emitting radiation: there were ideas about using a conventional engine on the ground (which brings the whole discussion back to the kind of engine / payload we can use now)

Comment: The question isn't "what could we send to space without causing radioactive emissions" @eddyce

Comment: @JCRM I would invite you to give details in your answer itself regarding the _why_ Project Orion could do it but _won't_ do it.

Comment: @JCRM and if you read I said "..never had a plan on how to use it before reaching orbit..." since orion engines don't exist yet this whole thing is just hypotetical unless the question is "what could we send to space with any possible future technology" then I'd say star trek teleport is a good option too

Comment: They planned to use the engines for launch @eddyce

Comment: @JCRM check this out https://space.stackexchange.com/a/5134/26543

Comment: @JCRM look, you want to believe we could launch an engine propelled with a pulse of nuclear hydrogen bombs on ground level, its fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80338/discussion-between-jcrm-and-eddyce).